# Dynamically created checkboxes in Windows Form only works when offsetting in the negative x direction

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating this windows form and I want to dynamically create an array of checkboxes. Here is my code:

```
Dim Checkboxes(NumberOfRows - 1, NumberOfColumns - 1)
Dim Posx, Posy As Integer
Posx = 10
Posy = 10
For RowCount = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1
    For ColumnCount = 0 To NumberOfColumns - 1
        Dim checkbox = New CheckBox
        Checkboxes(RowCount, ColumnCount) = checkbox
        Controls.Add(checkbox)
        checkbox.Location = New Point(Posx, Posy)
        Posx += 20
    Next
    Posy += 20
    Posx = 10
Next
```

The resulting form looks like this:

[image]

However, the checkboxes in the x-direction are not being shown. It works well in the y-direction though.

If I change `Posx += 20` to `Posx -= 20`, the dynamically created checkboxes appear, like so (array of checkboxes get cut off by the form's left boundary):

[image]

Why do the dynamically created checkboxes only appear when offsetting in the negative x-direction, while the y-direction is fine. Why does offsetting in the positive x-direction not work? How do I fix this?

Comment: Side note: you might consider using a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-windows-forms) or a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-windows-forms).

Comment: My guess would be that the controls offset to the right are actually behind that part of the other control intended for displaying text. Change the `BackColor` and it will be immediately obvious if that's the case.  If so, you'd have to change the `Width` too, or modify the z-order so that those on the right are shown in front of those on the left.

Comment: @jmcilhinney is right. I just tested that, and the default width is >20 (104 in my case). All you need to do is add `checkbox.Width = 20`, and it should work fine. However, using one of the `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` controls as mentioned above (depends on your requirements) helps you a lot so you don't have to set the locations manually.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yup, that was it, thanks a lot. I get it now. The default checkbox is actually a rectangular area in which the text extends to the right of the checkbox. I should've known when I clicked a bit to the right of the checkbox, the checkbox would still change value. The subsequent checkboxes offsetting to the right are then blocked by the previous checkboxes. And that's also why it works when going in the negative X direction.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks, I will check `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` out.